# Is it possible to copy a multi-OS image from one docker registry to another on a linux machine?

Tags: docker, containers, buildah

I need a way to copy my manifest and all related blobs/etc from a private registry to a public registry, where the images were never pushed to the public registry before.

I am successfully creating a multi-arch manifest via `buildah`. Note that while the image is built with buildah, I would be satisfied with a docker-based approach for copying the final result between registries. Here is the output from `buildah inspect`:

```
{
    "schemaVersion": 2,
    "manifests": [
        {
            "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
            "digest": "sha256:e1c1de1b56adc07e5a97970b3340b1cf71c02796eb4e27c638634b6bcf0e510e",
            "size": 5590,
            "platform": {
                "architecture": "amd64",
                "os": "windows"
            }
        },
        {
            "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
            "digest": "sha256:c4bf2b94bbedceab3888544f4b966e8c1435231daeff27546acaf3b817485226",
            "size": 511,
            "platform": {
                "architecture": "amd64",
                "os": "linux"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In reality, there will be even more permutations... but this simple manifest demonstrates the problem.

My CI pushes this image to a local registry, for performance (and various other) reasons. Once I have tested the final manifest, I want to push it to the public `docker.io` registry with the same tags.

Before I added Windows into the mix, I was able to accomplish this by pulling each image, retagging it with the new registry, and pushing. Something like...

```
buildah manifest create docker.io/img/name:latest

# Retag & add windows...
buildah pull myreg/img/name:windows
buildah tag myreg/img/name:windows docker.io/img/name:windows
buildah push docker.io/img/name:windows
buildah manifest add docker.io/img/name:latest docker.io/img/name:windows

# ... other variants ...
```

Unfortunately, this does not work with Windows. When the Linux machine tries to pull the Windows image, I receive the following error:

```
Error committing the finished image: error adding layer with blob "sha256:0363fe57a309a0e39c3dd1bb7be80beed88dcef74b1773ee1a37f6caf81e0fe2": Error processing tar file(exit status 1): link /Files/Program Files/common files/Microsoft Shared/Ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui /Files/Program Files (x86)/common files/Microsoft Shared/ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui: no such file or directory
```

Do I need to use a Windows machine for the retagging bit, where the image is copied from the local to public registry? Or is there a simple way to just copy/mirror an entire manifest without adding all these extra pull/tag/push steps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For copying between registries, you can hit the registry API without interacting with a docker engine or any other container runtime. The images are json manifests and compressed tar blobs described in the OCI image-spec, and the API's access to those on a registry is now covered by the OCI distribution-spec.

The most complicated part of this is typically handling the auth that may vary by registry server, otherwise it could be fairly easily implemented in a shell script with a variety of curl and jq commands. I ended up making my own tooling to handle this exact use case, available on [github.com/regclient/regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient). And for your specific request, you'd run:

```
regctl image copy myreg/img/name:latest docker.io/img/name:latest
```

Similar tools that I think implement these features include RedHat's skopeo and Google's crane (part of their go-containerregistry project).

Comment: Fantastic; it had always bothered me I needed a container runtime to interact with the API, when as you said, they are just json&tar files.

Answer (score 4):

There is an open-source tool [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo).

Quote:

> Copying an image from and to various storage mechanisms. For example
> you can copy images from one registry to another, without requiring
> privilege.

To just copy an image from one registry to another (from official [examples](https://github.com/containers/skopeo/blob/main/docs/skopeo-copy.1.md#examples)):

```bash
skopeo copy --all docker://quay.io/skopeo/stable:latest docker://registry.example.com/skopeo:latest
```